# reading a file in NLTK python

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to read a txt file using nltk and below is the code , i am new to nltk so am not sure about the working of it , but i am getting a error can anyone of you please specify if the error is because of some issue with text file or the code. Please find the code and the error message below. Thanks in advance for your help

code-

```
import nltk, re, pprint

from nltk import word_tokenize

f= open('MobyDick.txt')

raw=f.read()
```

Error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/DSTI/python/txt.py", line 4, in <module>
    raw=f.read()
  File "C:\Users\Pratik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7237: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Your problem is with `open()`, it has nothing to do with the nltk. You need to give `open()` the correct encoding for your file, e.g. `open("MobyDick.txt", encoding="latin1")`